# Android online database. How to deal with user filters?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im making my first Android app, it is for people who are looking for properties. I need an online database because I have a lot of pictures and the content of the database is regularly updated.

I'd like to display properties to users depending on their filters. Let's say they can choose a location, a range of prices, and whether they want to see properties with a garden or not.
I currently have a google sheet with one line per property (and in columns I have location, size, price, garden, and my picture urls). Now... I don't know what I have to do. I converted my google sheet in a json file to use it with firebase realtime database, but then how should I call it if a user wants to see all the properties from $260k to $290k, at least 520sqft, in California ? I learnt how to parse json files, but I don't know what I should parse there.

Should I use something else "before" or "instead" firebase realtime database ? I am sure that I am missing something, but I don't know what :D

Thank you for your help !

Comment: first learn how to use firebase database and how it works, you will figure it out

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer ! I watched à tuto about it a few days ago. From what I understand I have to "structure" my data infrastructure nodes, but I dont see how to do it for then being able to display my list of filtered properties. My goal was to make a node for each filter so I first started to make a node for properties with garden, then I realized that I cannot do it this way :D I cannot have a node for each price, and if  a user filters on both a price and a garden I dont not have a node for that. Do you see what i should do ?

Comment: Great to hear that you're considering using Firebase as your database. Unfortunately the scope of your question is incredibly broad and we won't be able to answer it in a reasonable size/time. I recommend reading a bit more on NoSQL and Firebase Database, experimenting with its query model and post back if you have a more concrete question. Recommended reading/watching: [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Hi Frank thank you for your recommandations, that seems to perfectly suit my needs !